# Why does GCC handle a const reinterpret_cast different when type alias is used?

Tags: c++, gcc

In the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>
class s;
void foo(void* buffer) {
    using s_ptr = s *;
    const auto b_s = reinterpret_cast<const s_ptr>(buffer);
    const auto b_s2 = reinterpret_cast<const s *>(buffer); 
}
```

Compiling with `-O3 -Werror=ignored-qualifiers` I got the error:

```
<source>: In function 'void foo(void*)':

<source>:5:22: error: type qualifiers ignored on cast result type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]

    5 |     const auto b_s = reinterpret_cast<const s_ptr>(buffer);

      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this a bug in GCC? Shouldn't both `reinterpret_cast` be the same?

Comment: Another to the collection of "leading const is misleading"

Comment: `using const_s_ptr = s const *;` then use that in the first cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
using s_ptr = s *;
```

the type `const s_ptr` actually becomes `s * const`, which is not the same as `const s *`.

I suggest writing `const` to the right hand side of the type you want to `const` qualify, like this:

```
reinterpret_cast<s_ptr const>(buffer);
reinterpret_cast<s const *>(buffer);
```

and now it's clear that `s_ptr const` is just `s * const`, which is not the same as `s const *`.

So yes, the `reinterpret_cast` is being given different types, and for the first cast, gcc is warning that the top-level `const` is ignored.